# How to disable gzip compression using htaccess

Tags: htaccess, gzip

I want to disable gzip compression in my site using htaccess.

I have the code below in htaccess:

```
php_flag zlib.output_compression off
```

But it is not working.

Comment: How is gzip compression currently implemented on your site? Do you wish to disable compression for the whole site, or just certain files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249243/how-to-disable-apache-gzip-compression-for-some-media-files-in-htaccess-file

It's possible, but looks like it will disable gzip for the whole website.

Keep in mind that you are telling PHP not to gzip, but Apache may still be gzipping so this should sort it, but check Apache config.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [NS,E=no-gzip:1,E=dont-vary:1]
```

Comment: In the linked question, "global" refers to the _whole site_, not "every site hosted on [the] server" - if that is what you were referring to?

Comment: @w3d Your right on that one. I'll update answer.

Answer (score 8):

A simpler one that also works:
`SetEnv no-gzip 1`

The line you were using disables PHP's compression. The `no-gzip` env variable, on the other hand, disables Apache compression.

Comment: Note that you need to enable apache module 'env' for this to work.